# Question about the Cauchy principal value

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, cauchy-principal-value

We're currently dealing with Cauchys principal value and I'm going through some textbook examples step by step to try and understand how they work.

Sadly there is step which I can't seem to understand, it's the following:
$$\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to0^+}\left[\int\limits_{\epsilon}^{\infty} \frac{1-e^{ix}}{x^2}dx+\int\limits_{-\epsilon}^{-\infty} \frac{1-e^{ix}}{x^2}dx\right] =$$
$$\int\limits_{C}\frac{1-e^{ix}}{x^2}dx-\lim\limits_{R\to\infty}\int\limits_{C_1}\frac{1-e^{ix}}{x^2}dx -\lim\limits_{r\to 0}\int\limits_{C_2}\frac{1-e^{ix}}{x^2}dx$$

With $C_1$ being the top part of a half circle with Radius $R$ (in the limes $R\to\infty)$ in the complex plane ($x=Re^{i\theta},0<\theta<\pi$).

$C_2$  being the top part of a half circle with Radius $r$ (in the limes $r\to0)$ in the complex plane ($x=re^{i\theta},0<\theta<\pi$)

The only other example of the Cauchy principal value I have seen was the one with $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x} \ dx $, but I don't know how the concepts used there apply to this example problem.

Why do the two integrals  get splitted into three and where does the curve $C$ come from?

I would really appreciate any kind of help. Thanks.

Comment: Your first limit is not a CPV. To be the CPV, it should be $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_\epsilon^\infty + \int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon}$$ Exchanging the limits changes the sign of the integral, which means you are no longer approaching the singularity of the same function equally from both sides.

Comment: Even with that correction, this is a hot mess. $C = C_1 \cup [-R,r] \cup (-C_2) \cup [r,R]$, where $-C_2$ is the reverse curve from $C_2$. $C$ depends on both $R$ and $r$, but it is a closed curve and the integrand is holomorphic inside, so the integral around it is always $0$. Because of the $-$ on $C_2$, its integral is added, not subtracted, and you get $$CPV\int_{-\infty}^\infty = \lim_{r\to 0^+}\int_{C_2} - \lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{C_1}$$The first term is half the residue at $0$. For the second term, note that the numerator is bounded.